# how can i get an object in templates by using django sessions?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

so basically im making an E-commerce website. and i want to implement sessions in it.
i stored product.id as a key and product.quantity as a value in a dictionary called cart and stored in the session

`request.session['cart'] = cart`

if i print request.session['cart'], it prints keys and values like this

`{'10': 2, '15': 1, '11': 1}`

as it should be but i wanna do is to get product object in templates by this session. i wanna get all the product details(name,price, etc) by its id in cart.html

is there any way i can do that? should i use custom template filter and how can i use that?

**Code**

```
        id = request.POST.get('id')    
        obj_id = Product.objects.get(id=id)
        cart = request.session.get('cart')
        if cart:
            quantity = cart.get(id)
            if quantity:
                cart[id]= quantity+1
            else:
                cart[id] = 1
        else:
            
            cart={}
            cart[id] = 1
        request.session['cart'] = cart
        print(cart)
        return redirect('index')
```

what i was doing is store product obj as key in cart but it showed an error..

Comment: which error? can you place traceback?

Comment: "keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not Product"

Comment: @subhan_malik - where you See product as Key?